# Почему SELECT COUNT(*) выполняется дольше SELECT *?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть такой запрос

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM `t` 
WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2020-05-19' AND '2020-05-20' 
AND `ref_id` IS NOT NULL 
AND `field` = 0
```

Есть составной индекс `ref_id, field, date`.

В результате запроса мы получаем число около 30-40, для периода в 1 день.

Запрос выполняется за 0.2 секунды, не смотря на то, что индекс покрывающий.
EXPLAIN показывает, что индекс используется, что SELECT_TYPE: SIMPLE, TYPE: range, EXTRA: Using where; Using index

Но несмотря на, вроде бы, подходящий индекс запрос выполняется сравнительно долго, учитывая, что он выполняется сотни тысяч раз в день.

Если в запросе просто убрать COUNT и оставить SELECT *, то время выполнения будет 0.09 секунд, в 2 раза быстрее.

И вот вопрос почему запрос с COUNT выполняется в 2 раза дольше? Ведь если мы используем COUNT, то запрос использует только данные из индекса, это видно в `EXPLAIN EXTRA: Using where; Using index`. А когда мы используем просто SELECT *, то `EXTRA: Using index condition`

И в конце концов как ускорить этот запрос?

Comment: Скокько записей в таблице, какая селективность по условиям в целом и по каждому отдельно?

Comment: @t0lik 2.5 млн записей. COUNT по условию ref_id IS NULL: 125007, по условию `field` = 0 : 1539789, по условию date BETWEEN .... : 95, по полному условию 36.

Comment: Можете попробовать индекс только дате, тем более что тут по диапазону идет и составной индекс думаю будет неэффективен. Также см. https://ruhighload.com/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%8B+%D0%B2+mysql

Comment: @t0lik да, я уже сделал и это сработало. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо @t0lik за наводку. Дело в том, что составной индекс сослужит плохую службу. Для ускорения запроса было достаточно создать индекс date, так как его селективность наилучшая и её достаточно для выполнения запроса.

Но почему COUNT(*) выполнялся дольше чем SELECT * я так и не выяснил. Но это и не важно если запрос работает пару микросекунд.